# Using SSH command on website

Tags: magento-1.9, websites, shell

For executing magento patches, we need to use **SSH command lines**

```
e.g. sh patch_file_name.sh
```

But I wonder where to put this command lines? on Hosting site? on FTP client? Please advise. Thanks for help!

I am using windows 7 and using Filezilla as connection tool

Comment: Hosting system on which os?

Comment: Actually i just want to run the magento patch files.. can i just run the file in **Myphpadmin** ? Instead of installing the SSH tools?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run in ssh. You can use [Putty](http://www.putty.org/)

This [guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-SSH) will tell you about using ssh.

Or you can use some **SFTP** to run the code. For example this [service](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

**Remember you need to have ssh access for your server. If you do not have ssh access, then ask your server provider.**

Comment: Is possible can i reindex my localhost magento using putty.

Answer (score 0):

To install security patches provided by the Magento first,

You need to upload the downloaded patch file to your websites `root` folder, Where your Magento site's code is placed.

For my case, I am using magento on nginx, on ubuntu server so for me it is:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/magentosetup
```

2. Copy the `patch_file_name.sh` in the installation Directory.

execute this file using the `sh` command like below:

`sh patch_file_name.sh`

it will install the patch into your magento setup.

But, yes for this you must have ssh access to your server